# jQuery Soundboard - Playing ONE Button turns off all the other buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, audio, dynamic

I am creating a jQuery/PHP soundboard and I am trying to figure out how to code if I click ONE button, that stops the HTML5 Audio attached to all the other buttons.  Here's my code so far:

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {
            $("audio").removeAttr("controls").each(function(i, audioElement) {
                var audio = $(this);
                var that = this; //closure to keep reference to current audio tag
                $("#doc").append(
                    $('<button>'+audio.attr("title")+'</button>').toggle(
                        function() {
                            that.play();
                            $(this).addClass('playing');
                        }, 
                        function(){
                            that.pause(); that.currentTime = 0;
                            $(this).removeClass('playing');
                        }));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php foreach($files as $file) { ?>
     <?php $title = str_replace(".mp3", "", str_replace("clips/", "", $file)); ?>
     <audio src="<?php echo $file; ?>" controls autobuffer="true" title="<?php echo $title ?>"></audio>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modified jQuery:**

```
$('<button>'+audio.attr("title")+'</button>').click(
   function(e) {
      var playing = $(this).hasClass("playing");
      $("audio").each(function(i, audioElement){
         this.pause();
         this.currentTime = 0;
      });

      $("button").each(function( i ) {
         $(this).removeClass('playing');
      });

      if (!playing){
         that.play();
         $(this).addClass('playing');
      }
   })
);
$("audio").bind("ended", function(){ $("button").removeClass('playing'); });
```

**Explanation:**

When you CLICK any button, it declares a variable IF the button has a class of *PLAYING*.  Then, it automatically STOPS all audio and rewinds them to 0. It then removes the class PLAYING form every button. Finally, it checks if the button you just click has a class of *PLAYING*; if it does not, then it adds the class *PLAYING* to the button, and plays the audio attached to that button.

The added line at the bottom fires when the audio is done playing, the class *PLAYING* is automatically removed